# Using TexMaker, why is `lipsum.sty' not found?

Tags: lipsum

I am using TexMaker 4.5. I've seen similar questions that did not help. I've had my resume working before and after a years worth of updates on my Linux box, I now try to run my *.tex file and get the following error.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `lipsum.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.8 \usepackage
{enumitem}^^M
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5220 strings out of 494939
75903 string characters out of 6179320
165580 words of memory out of 5000000
8543 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
28i,0n,35p,207b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

After running, the line that gets highlighted has this ...

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

Comment: Do other documents work? Can you reproduce the problem with a minimal document that you can add to your question?

Comment: This is unrelated to texmaker, that is just the editor you are using, you can install lipsum package using your miktex or texlive or linux package manager (depending on which tex distribution you have)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - I did give that a try, adding lipsum. So I probably don't have it installed then. I searched my package database and haven't found a package called lipsum and I guess that's what's confusing me. It must be packaged under another name which I have yet to find.

Comment: @AlanMunn - I can do other less complicated docs fine. Eventually if I can't get this after confirming lipsum is installed, I'll try to put one together.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - If you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it. I just installed a meta package that covers lots of smaller packages and it seems to be working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style file lipsum.sty is from package lipsum.

You need to be aware that this package provides "sample"text which has no meaning.  It is used to illustrate the format of a document.

If the *.tex which is your resume worked previously with actual personal data (ie not a template), then you need to examine your preamble carefully to verify you have not input that style file.  (Be careful to check any 'input' commands in the preamble to verify they do not contain a call to lipsum. ).

Do a search in your document and any preamble input file for 'lips'

This is another reason to be very careful with templates as they often result in the file have calls to packages not being used by the document.

Answer (score 0):

`.sty` files sometimes do not get automatically installed along with `Latex-mk`or `latex-core` packages. Your Linux machine could be missing `latex-extra` package which includes the `lipsum.sty` files along with others.

To install `latex-extra` on arch linux for *texlive* based latex versions:
`sudo pacman -S texlive-latexextra`

You can find similar commands to install the package on other Linux distributions.